# Is there a difference starting from front v/s back in dynamic programming problems?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

In dynamic programming problems, does it ever matter whether you start from the front or the back?

Right now, I'm thinking no because even in optimization problems, where say, `fun(n) = some penalty + fun(n-1)`, here `fun(n-1)` is independent of the value at `n`. Which means, we could very well have calculated `fun(n-1)` starting from the beginning and then added the penalty.

Can you please give me an example.

Answer (score 2):

To my understanding, in the context of dynamic programming, "starting from the back" is simply recursion without actually using dynamic programming. If the results of overlapping subproblems are stored in a cache, this is called "memoization", which attains the same runtime complexity as dynamic programming, but is not considered "dynamic programming in the strictest sense" by some. In total, "starting from the front" without an auxiliary data structure to perform the memoization definitely is dynamic programming by consensus.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the property of reversing the input is related to dynamic programming, in your example it's related to the Commutative property of addition. A problem that you cannot reverse the input and get the same result is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence. And it is solved by dynamic programming.